# ASP.NET MVC Keep Session Alive from a Thread

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, session

I have a scenario in which I start a new thread from an action where the thread will perform some background work. Sometimes if the thread is taking some longer time to complete the work, the session seems to get expired. Is there any way to keep the session alive from the new thread?

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid accessing any HttpContext resources such as Session in your background threads. You could pass the information this thread needs as a parameter.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Get the value you will need from the session
    SomeModel model = (SomeModel)Session["myModel"];

    // start a new Thread
    Thread thread = new Thread(DoWork);
    thread.Start(model);

    return View();
}

private void DoWork(object state)
{
    SomeModel model = (SomeModel)state;
    // do the work here without ever accessing the HttpContext
}
```

And if you need information from multiple sources such as Sessions, Models, Cookies, whatever, ... simply build a new model which will aggregate them all:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public SomeModelFromSession SessionData { get; set; }
    public SomeModelFromCookie CookieData { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then pass this new model to your background thread when starting it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I feel that the problem is different. Actually, the action receives a file that user uploads and saves the file locally, and the thread moves it to Amazon S3. So I think the session gets expired as the file is being received by the action even before the thread is called. So I have to rephrase my question as "How to keep the session alive while a large file is being uploaded to an ASP.NET application?"

Comment: So the problem is that the session expires before you start uploading the file to Amazon and before you have even started the thread?

Comment: Yes, suppose the file size is about 100MB, it takes some time (like 20 minutes on a slow connection) to be completely uploaded to the web host where it gets saved first before being moved to S3. During this time, the session gets expired. Is that normal? If so, is there any way to hold the session until the upload is completed.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the file to your local file system, have session/necessary data serialized to a json file with the same file name (or write that information to database).

My suggestions are;

- This should be handled by a separate windows service or a running executable on the background.
- If you want the web application to handle this, you can create a thread when the web application starts, and checks for new files uploaded to upload to S3. But the drawback of this, you cannot know when IIS recycles the web application, and some scenarios, you can have more than one instance of the same web application (depending on the configuration of the application pool). So you have to handle application restarts and having multiple instances gracefully.
- Or maybe you can use a Queue system (MSMQ, database maybe)
- You can even use, Redis or database.